# Resque PHP (Redis error?)

Tags: php, redis, resque

I'm trying to use [PHP Resque](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque) (which uses Redis via redisent), but I keep getting this error:

```
Warning: fsockopen() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in 
/home/***/public_html/codes/ao/resque/lib/Redisent/Redisent.php on line 56

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message ' - ' in 
/home/***/public_html/codes/ao/resque/lib/Redisent/Redisent.php:58 Stack trace: #0 
/home/***/public_html/codes/ao/resque/lib/Redisent/Redisent.php(52): Redisent-
>establishConnection() #1 /home/***/public_html/codes/ao/resque/lib/Resque.php(38): 
Redisent->__construct('redis', '//***') #2 /home/***/public_html/cons/db.php(6): 
Resque::setBackend('redis://***...') #3 {main} thrown in 
/home/***/public_html/codes/ao/resque/lib/Redisent/Redisent.php on line 58
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. Please help me!

Answer (score 3):

The very first line of your error dump shows the problem.

```
fsockopen() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in 
  in /home/***/public_html/codes/ao/resque/lib/Redisent/Redisent.php on line 56
```

The second parameter of [fsockopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) is supposed to be a port number. Somehow, you're passing a string into it.

The rest of the errors that follow are simply due to the failed connection.

In looking at the [Redisent.php source code](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque/blob/master/lib/Redisent/Redisent.php), it looks like you must be passing an invalid parameter to the constructor of your Redisent object.

In your source code, where you have something like:

```
$foo = new Redisent('hostname', '32323'); // See the bug?
```

...make sure the second parameter is not a string.

The following would be correct:

```
$foo = new Redisent('hostname', 32323); // no quotes around port number!
```

Comment: When I `run:fsockopen('redis://neex1233:**************************@stingfish.redistogo.com:  9154/');`     I get this error:
`Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to redis://neex1233:***************************@stingfish.redistogo.com:9154 (Unable to find the socket transport "redis" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?) in /home/username/public_html/cons/db.php on line 6`   I'm guessing this has something to do with it.

Comment: This is another obvious one.

Lose the "redis://" prefix. The first parameter is simply the hostname. Redisent.php does not add a PHP socket transport. This is all right there in the Redisent documentation.

Please mark my original answer as accepted. Thanks!